# Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server

Why gives this code next error on the last line?

> Invalid column name 'rId'.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT Id as rId
    FROM Roles
    WHERE Minimum >= (select punten 
                      from Users 
                      where id = 'abc')
)
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId) 
VALUES ('abc', rId);
```

I use MS-SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it! The code must be this:

```
;WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT Id 
    FROM AspNetRoles
    WHERE Minimum >= (select punten from AspNetUsers where id = 'abc')
)
INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
SELECT 'abc', rs.id
FROM rs;
```

Comment: Or just `INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles (UserId, RoleId)
SELECT 'abc', Id FROM AspNetRoles WHERE Minimum >= (select punten from AspNetUsers where id = 'abc');`. On a different note, please consider putting semicolons at the end of each statement rather than at the beginning – that's where they are supposed to be.